# Why is "embaixo" together but "em cima" separated? (Por que "embaixo" é junto mas "em cima" separado?)

Tags: ortografia, português-brasileiro, advérbios

If "em cima" were together, it would be "encima", but instead, "em cima" is separated. However "embaixo" is together, and "em baixo" is incorrect, when the intention is to indicate location.

What would be the reason for that? Some phonetic reason or what?

---

Eu nunca tinha percebido antes esse detalhe.
Se fosse junto, seria "encima", mas ao invés disso, "em cima" é separado. Porém "embaixo" é junto, e é incorreto "em baixo", quando a intenção é indicar local.

Qual seria o motivo disso? Alguma razão fonética ou o quê?

Comment: [No português europeu, é usada a locução "em baixo".](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/embaixo).

Comment: Porque é que "tudo junto" é separado e "separado" é tudo junto? :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Segundo [este site](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/em-baixo-ou-embaixo/) em Portugal usa-se **em baixo** e no Brasil **embaixo**, o meu corretor ortográfico também diz o mesmo (dá erro em embaixo).

---

Depois de uma prolongada pesquisa descobri que isso acontece por 
uma questão de fonética e também de ortografia. Os fonemas bilabiais “m” e “b” se 
adaptam facilmente na língua portuguesa, além de ser admitida a união entre os 
mesmos. Agora, no caso de “em cima” seria necessária a troca do “m” pelo “n”, o que 
não é aceite ortograficamente, contudo, é muito comum encontrarmos “encima”, erradamente.

Fonte: [Como utilizar corretamente as palavras](http://stoa.usp.br/clinicadotexto/forum/43064.html)

---

Por curiosidade **encima**, escrito de forma junta, é a forma do verbo **encimar** conjugado na 3.ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo ou na 2.ª pessoa do singular do imperativo. **Encimar** se refere ao ato de colocar ou se situar em cima ou no alto, bem como ao ato de coroar.

> Um chapéu verde ***encima*** a cabeça daquela senhora

Fonte: [Em cima ou encima](http://www.normaculta.com.br/em-cima-ou-encima/)

---

Comment: Bom, pelo que pude ver, ninguém em lugar algum sabe dizer o porquê de embaixo ser junto, apenas que o português tem irregularidades e que embaixo é uma delas. Mas pelo que se pode perceber, a causa só pode ser a relação entre o `b` de "baixo" e o `m` de "em". O mistério é: por que juntá-los?

Answer (score 6):

- **Embaixo**:
  É um *advérbio de lugar* que transmite uma ideia de algo que está em lugar inferior a outro: abaixo, debaixo, inferiormente, ou seja, numa posição de inferioridade.

  > Ex.: Ele está embaixo da cama.
- **Em baixo**:
  A expressão *em baixo*, escrita de forma separada, existe. É usada apenas quando a palavra **baixo** assume a função de um *adjetivo* (contrário de **alto**), caracterizando algo.

  > Ex.: Falou em baixo tom de voz.

Provavelmente a palavra **embaixo** foi criada justamente para diferenciar isso. Digo, enquanto o **baixo** de *embaixo* tem como contrário (a palavra) **cima**. O **baixo** de *em baixo* tem como contrário (a palavra) **alto**.
E é bem provável que **encima** não seja utilizado por ser a conjugação em 3ª pessoa do verbo **encimar** (como já disse o Jorge).

Comment: "enquanto o baixo de embaixo tem como contrário (a palavra) cima. O baixo de embaixo tem como contrário (a palavra) alto."  Mas é "cima" ou "alto"?

Comment: Editado @BrunoLopes. Pequeno erro de digitação.

Comment: Que clareza. :)