# Qual a diferença entre as palavras "embaixo" e "em baixo"?

Tags: ortografia, advérbios, adjetivos, português-brasileiro

A palavra embaixo é usada como advérbio de lugar, exemplo:

> O cachorro estava embaixo da cama.

Quando empregamos "em baixo" separadamente?

Existem diferenças no emprego dessas palavras entre Brasil e Portugal e outro países?

Comment: Related: [Por que “embaixo” é junto mas “em cima” separado?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/566/why-is-embaixo-together-but-em-cima-separated-por-que-embaixo-%C3%A9-junto-ma)

Comment: Tranquilamente "em baixo" é o contrário de "em alto" -> Falou em baixo tom. Enquanto "embaixo" é o antônimo de "em cima".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"embaixo é um advérbio e "em baixo" é uma preposição + adjetivo.** No Brasil não usamos a locução adverbial "em baixo".

- "Ele se escondeu **embaixo** da cama."
- "O açúcar está no armário **embaixo** da pia."
- "Tu poderias ouvir essa música **em baixo** som?"
- "Ele falava **em baixo** calão".